# Finding a partial sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was hoping someone could help me find the sum of this series:

$S_N=\sum^N_{n=0} \frac{1}{(n-\frac{3}{2})(n-\frac{1}{2})(n+\frac{3}{2})(n+\frac{5}{2})}$

I know that it should evaluate to

$S_N=\frac{16}{3}\frac{N+1}{(2N-1)(2N+1)(2N+3)(2N+5)}$,

and using the telescopic method I get the denominator reasonably close (up to a constant), but I can't seem to find the actual answer. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what exactly doesn't work if you try to telescope?

Comment: I assume you mean that you attempted to write this series as a telescoping series using partial fraction decomposition. Would it be possible to write down your attempt to at this computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  mind the symmetry:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\left((n+\frac{1}{2})-2\right)\left((n+\frac{1}{2})-1\right)\left((n+\frac{1}{2})+1\right)\left((n+\frac{1}{2})+2\right)} & =\frac{1}{\left((n+\frac{1}{2})^2-1\right)\left((n+\frac{1}{2})^2-4\right)} \\[5px]
 & = \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{(n+\frac{1}{2})^2-4}-\frac{1}{(n+\frac{1}{2})^2-1}\right)
\end{align}
$$

---

[ *EDIT* ]  Furthermore, with $a_n=\cfrac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}}\,$:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat}{2}
\frac{1}{(n+\frac{1}{2})^2-4} & = \frac{1}{4}\left( \frac{1}{(n+\frac{1}{2})-2} - \frac{1}{(n+\frac{1}{2})+2}\right) && = \frac{1}{4}(a_{n-2}-a_{n+2}) \\
\frac{1}{(n+\frac{1}{2})^2-1} & = \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{1}{(n+\frac{1}{2})-1} - \frac{1}{(n+\frac{1}{2})+1}\right) && = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1}-a_{n+1})
\end{alignat}
\end{cases}
$$

Summing up and telescoping:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
S_N & = \frac{1}{12}\sum_{n=0}^N (a_{n-2}-a_{n+2}) - \frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=0}^N (a_{n-1}-a_{n+1}) \\[5px]
& = \frac{1}{12}(a_{\,-2}+a_{\,-1}+a_0+a_1 - a_{N-1} - a_{N} - a_{N+1} - a_{N+2}) -\frac{1}{6}(a_{\,-1}+a_0-a_N-a_{N+1}) \\[5px]
& = \frac{1}{12}(\cancel{a_{\,-2}}-\bcancel{a_{\,-1}}-\bcancel{a_0}+\cancel{a_1} - a_{N-1} + a_{N} + a_{N+1} - a_{N+2})
\end{align}
$$

Noting that $a_{n-1}-a_n=\cfrac{4}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}$ the latter reduces to:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
S_N &= \frac{4}{12}\left(-\frac{1}{(2N-1)(2N+1)} + \frac{1}{(2N+3)(2N+5)} \right) \\[5px]
&= \frac{1}{3}\,\frac{\bcancel{4N^2} -1 - \bcancel{4N^2} - 16N -15}{(2N-1)(2N+1)(2N+3)(2N+5)} =  \\[5px]
& =  -\,\frac{16}{3}\,\frac{N+1}{(2N-1)(2N+1)(2N+3)(2N+5)}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but ultimately, I couldn't find anywhere to go with this. I ended up finding my own solution (with Mathematica), which I've posted below.

Comment: @Karl I edited the answer and filled in the blanks. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I've come to a solution to my own problem. Given that I was having trouble doing the so called telescopic solution where I write the full term as a sum of partial fractions and try to find terms that cancel, I went about it a separate way with Mathematica (not very math rigorous, but it works for me).

My solution was as follows. I reversed the sum so that I could include the final number N in the sum itself:

$\sum^N_{n=0} \frac{1}{(N-n-\frac{3}{2})(N-n-\frac{1}{2})(N-n+\frac{3}{2})(N-n+\frac{5}{2})}$

I then summed to a specific N value, call it L=40, such that my solution came out as follows:

$\frac{656}{(2N-1)(2N+1)(2N+3)(2N+5)}\left(\frac{-332483-299208L+32008L^2-1248L^3+16L^4}{(2L-83)(2L-81)(2L-79)(2L-77)}\right)$

Noting that $656=16(L+1)$ where L = 40, and plugging in 40 for L in the ugly looking fraction on the right, it reduced to $-\frac{1}{3}$, which is the answer I was looking for (up to a minus sign that I missed in the question).

Thanks for everyone's help above. :)